# New "Tab level" view in Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-routing

I have a tabs project. I handle new views and new controllers but I'm now stuck in a situation:

I would like to create a welcome screen (for logging/account creation) before reaching the tabs. So I created a templates/welcome.html file that contains:

```
<ion-view view-title="Welcome">
  <ion-content class="padding">
      <p>hello</p><br>
      <a class="button button-block button-positive"
         nav-direction="forward"
         href="#/tab-dash">Tabs</a>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Then I registered this new page in the app router:

```
.state('welcome', {
    url: '/welcome',
    views: {
      'welcome': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/welcome.html',
        controller: 'WelcomeCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

Created the controller

```
.controller('WelcomeCtrl', function($scope) {})
```

Finally, I created a link to this page in one of the tab

```
<a class="button button-block button-positive"
      nav-direction="forward"
      href="#/welcome">Welcome</a>
```

I also set it up as default landing page by doing:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/welcome');
```

**Both the link doesn't send to page and going to the url #/welcome gives a blank page with the empty nav view bar.**

I found a solution with $state.transitionTo(...) but I have the same wrong result.

Comment: :Can you show code through plunker /codepen/jsfiddle?

Comment: What does it say in the JavaScript console output? Did you add the controller js file to the index.html?

Comment: Hi Thank you for your answers, my console doesn't trigger anything special. The controller is declared as part of the module "starter.controllers" which is reference in the index.html at the line angular.module(..., 'starter.controllers', ...)

Comment: I did not found where to handle multiple files on jsfiddle so I went back to my code and tried again a button with ng-click calling $state.transitionTo. The promise result is success... So I added <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
    <ion-nav-view name="welcome"></ion-nav-view> and this gave a space for my page to be displayed. I have the feeling to do it in a wrong way because it's not nested. I will try to create some state like begin.wecome and begin.tabs.tab1 etc... Is there another way to do ? Thx again guys !

Comment: I'm now understanding better what I have to do: 

start (abstract)
-- welcome
-- tabs (abstract ?)
---- tab_1
---- tab_2

I'm now trying to understand more the example here https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router#multiple--named-views but if someone can give me a hint ^^ thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have registered your welcome screen in angular.module() usually found in your app.js file.

```
angular.module('tag', ['ionic', 'WelcomeCtrl'])
```

It is a bit hard to help with the limited code you have pasted.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

My controller is registered in controller.js with :

angular.module('starter.controllers', [])
...
.controller('WelcomeCtrl', function($scope) {})
...

and my App has

angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ionic.service.core', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services']).

The problem persist...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the state : it was not registering the view itself but a contained view. This is the working configuration.

```
.state('welcome', {
    url: '/welcome',
    templateUrl: 'templates/welcome.html',
    controller: 'WelcomeCtrl'
})
```